# Upstart script that displays errors to the console?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, upstart

I have a simple upstart script that runs a process and respawns it if it crashes. The problem is if it crashes I want the user to be alerted that it crashed (because they may need to take an action to prevent it from crashing again). Here's my script:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

chdir /opt

respawn
respawn limit 5 10

exec /usr/bin/gulp --gulpfile ./lib/vendor/node/gulpfile.js 2>&1 > /var/log/gulp.log
```

Not that I redirect standard error into the console (2>&1) and standard out a log file. The log file redirection WORKS. But the standard error to the console does NOT. This error redirection *does* work if I run the command directly from the shell.

Things I've tried so far:
- Adding 'console output' to the script (which supposedly redirects output to /dev/console)
- Using exec start-stop-daemon --start -c myuser --exec command (thinking that because I run the upstart job with sudo the /dev/console points somewhere else) **this script just crashes won't even run

Any other ideas? I really need error output to be put into the console for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `2>&1` - this actually redirects stderr to stdout. You want stderr to go to the console - which is the default for stderr.

```
exec /usr/bin/gulp --gulpfile ./lib/vendor/node/gulpfile.js > /var/log/gulp.log
```